# ASP.NET Pages Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I’m getting a strange problem with an ASP.NET web application that is in production. The problem is that pages intermittently don’t render correctly (see screen shot below). It isn’t one particular page in the application or one particular use that is having the problem.

More information: The web server is IIS and the pages were published using the publish option in VS2008.

I wondered if anyone else has had a similar problem or has any ideas of how to pin this down?

[image]

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: Sounds more like network problem, i.e. server sending incomplete response to the browser. To verify this, use tools like HttpWatch to monitor the raw response..

Answer (score 1):

This can be because of html-encoding during publishing. `<` symbol is being replaced for the `&lgt;`.
How do you publish your pages?